# Symbol lookup error

Tags: vala

Trying to compile [this simple example](https://gitlab.com/gavr123456789/vala-snippets/-/tree/master/Fast-Examples/DazzleChart), but having this error when trying to run `exec`:

```
~/projects/vala-snippets/Fast-Examples/DazzleChart(master ✔) meson build
The Meson build system
Version: 0.49.2
Source dir: /home/stsdc/projects/vala-snippets/Fast-Examples/DazzleChart
Build dir: /home/stsdc/projects/vala-snippets/Fast-Examples/DazzleChart/build
Build type: native build
Project name: exec
Project version: undefined
Native C compiler: ccache cc (gcc 7.4.0 "cc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0")
Native Vala compiler: valac (valac 0.40.19)
Build machine cpu family: x86_64
Build machine cpu: x86_64
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.1)
Dependency glib-2.0 found: YES 2.56.4
Dependency libdazzle-1.0 found: YES 3.35.3
Build targets in project: 1
Found ninja-1.8.2 at /usr/bin/ninja
~/projects/vala-snippets/Fast-Examples/DazzleChart(master ✗) cd build 
~/projects/vala-snippets/Fast-Examples/DazzleChart/build(master ✗) ninja
[3/3] Linking target exec.
~/projects/vala-snippets/Fast-Examples/DazzleChart/build(master ✗) ./exec
./exec: symbol lookup error: ./exec: undefined symbol: dzl_graph_view_model_iter_set_value
```

Comment: According to https://valadoc.org/libdazzle-1.0/Dazzle.GraphModel.iter_set_value.html,  the method is avilable in libdazzle-1.0 since 3.30. I can only seem to be able to install 3.28.1. Can you detail on how you got version 3.35.3 ?

Comment: cloned from official repo and installed

Comment: Got it, managed to get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an old `libdazzle-1.0.so` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. pkg-config used it instead of freshly compiled version 3.35.3, which was installed at `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Removed one at `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and now it works.